# Compiled PHP is missing libphp?

Tags: php

I just compiled `PHP 7.3.0 alpha1` from the source, OS X, and then I installed Apache 2.2.4, but my PHP files aren't executed - instead I just see the code written in the file.

Like this:

[image]

I looked in httpd.conf, and I wasn't loading libphp7.so, but the module was nowhere to be found in the PHP source folder, I tried using libphp7.so from another PHP installation but `phpinfo();` would just show an old PHP version.

How do I get the libphp7.so after compiling PHP from source?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you compiled PHP and how you configured your webserver?

Comment: I used `./configure --enable-maintainer-zts \ --enable-debug \ --enable-cli` and then `make`. As for the webserver, I just ran `brew install httpd`

Comment: I followed this article: https://www.sammyk.me/compiling-php-from-source-writing-tests-for-php-source, since I hadn't compiled PHP before

Comment: And why did you compile it on your own? How did you configure the webserver? It does not magically know that it has to handle some PHP related stuff

Comment: I compiled PHP since there isn't a precompiled version available, since it's 7.3.0 alpha, it hasn't been released yet. The only thing I need for httpd.conf is to `LoadModule php7_module libphp7.so`, but I don't have the libphp module...

Comment: Then have a look at tutorials like https://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html that tell you how to build the Apache module - you have not provided any configuration options for your makefile

Answer (score 0):

You can get the libphp7.so file when source compiling using apxs2. 
You'll need to make sure you have the devel packages for aspx, mysql-devel package for mysql_config, and httpd-devel. For CentOS/RHEL you can just run the following

```
yum install httpd-devel
yum install libxml2-devel
yum install mysql-devel
```

For the configure I ran it with mysqlnd but if you want to run it with something else, you can change the with-mysqli/with-pdo-mysql. I also enabled cli but for the .so you'll need aspx2.

```
./configure --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-cli --with-apxs2
```

You can also set a prefix when compiling and it should be installed under [PREFIX PATH]/libs/libphp7.so.